# Candy Crush level 210: how to clear licorice?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I understand you have to get two candy bombs together. When I do this they only clear the right side, and not the licorice on the left side.  What am I doing wrong?

Level 210:

[image: Level 210]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused with what are candy bombs and what are color bombs. You should combine two of these:

[image: Color bomb]

A candy bomb is something like this:

[image: candy bomb]

Obviously nothing happens if you combine two of those, If you combine two of the first (the candy bombs), the whole field should be lasered, and you get rid of all the licorice on the left side. Although some people are complaining this is not working ([source](http://candycrush-cheats.com/level-210/)), but this should be the way to do it. So if it is not working, try again, it should work in the end.

Comment: Pretty sure OP was referring to wrapped candies as "candy bombs".

Answer (score 0):

Combining the color bombs works on the mobile version but not the pc version. I have tried multiple times on pc and they only clear the right side. Try playing on the mobile version. The combined color bombs do clear both sides on mobile.